# vb.net compare two tables and find differences

Tags: vb.net, datatable, compare

I have two tables with the same strucure. a.ID*(varchar(10))*, a.CODE_ASS*(varchar(1))*  and b.ID*(varchar(10))*, b.CODE_ASS*(varchar(1))*

Table "a" contains 2010 data, and table "b" contain 2013 data.

These two tables should doesn't have the same number of rows in each, but common IDs should be identical. I need to compare tables and find differences.

[image]

As you can see in this example, green rows are ok, and red one should be an error.
ID 2, 4 and 5 are errors because there are some differences. ID 6, in "a" table, is ok even if it has been deleted in table "b".

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using SQL tables, if you write a query to join the data on ID and select only where the values are different. Do you really want to assume that 0 = NULL?

```
SELECT a.ID FROM a INNER JOIN  b ON a.ID = b.ID WHERE a.ID<>b.ID;
```

If you want 0 = NULL then you need to change NULLs to 0 - that would look like the following.

```
SELECT a.ID FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID WHERE ISNULL(a.ID,0)<>ISNULL(b.ID,0);
```

ISNULL(param, value) will change the NULL to the value, in this case 0.

I am guessing you are using a recordset object so then all you have to do is loop through the results.

Comment: it seems perfect! tks! I was looking for a VB.net console script, but... your solution works!